# Flow: Dynamics 365 and Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate, dynamics-365

I have a database in Azure and I would like to bring over all the data from there into Dynamics 365. I have listed the following scenarios. I want to know if these scenarios are possible using Flow.

- Initial import of all data from Azure to Dynamics 365 (is this possible using Flow?)
- When a new record is created in Azure, Flow should be able to update it in Dynamics 365. Is this possible?
- When a existing record is updated in Azure, Flow should be able to update it in Dynamics 365. Is this possible?
- When an existing record is deleted in Azure, Flow should be able to delete it in Dynamics 365. Is this possible?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think all of these are possible.

Flow has connectors for [SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/sql/) and [Dynamics 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/dynamicscrmonline). You can also create [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/register-custom-api) connectors if those don't do what you need.

Comment: Thanks James! But there are no triggers for when a record is deleted in SQL Server. How should that be looked at?